# How to efficiently optimize search by geographical location?

Tags: java, sql, search, geolocation, query-optimization

I am creating a search for a local-goods delivery service, which is designed to limit a user to only seeing items within a reasonable road-distance.

The problem is that finding an accurate road-distance seems like it would require an unreasonably long search time, as it would require plotting the roads between every set of addresses.

Is there an effective way to estimate road distance based on a pure coordinate/address value from an SQL database?

Comment: I think there are specialized solutions for there where the distance is pre-calculated for intermediate points.

Comment: The best approximation you're likely to get without some kind of roads database is just raw "straight line" distance, which isn't a terrible approximation.